# Why camera doesn't appear althought I used Camera.getDefaut();?

Tags: android, camera, neomad

As the title, Can you hepl me to use the Camera class on NeoMAD??
Thanks for reading and excuse my bad English.

Comment: Hi,

To get a better support here, you should provide the source code that does not work, and describe more precisely the problem that you are facing.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the CameraExample sample located in the Examples folder of your NeoMAD install folder ? You should find what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank answering me.
Yes, I did but when I install CameraExample.apk to my Phone,I just can choose the photos from gallery.When I touched the camera to take a photo, it canceled the Apps.